# getting error when using ansible Kerberos

Tags: ansible, winrm

I create 2 servers, windows and Linux. Linux is for ansible runner machine, windows as host machine.
Through the Linux ansible machine, login to host windows machine and install tools. In Linux ansible machine installed all tools, windows host machine is domain joined, but not for Linux. we don't have domain join for Linux. Now I'm trying to authenticate with Kerberos. I'm getting some errors.

Kerberos ref link I used: (user authentication process)
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.3.1/html/administration/kerberos_auth.html

[image: winrm authentication process]

[image: screenshot for kerberos testing]

see above screenshot, I added Kerberos config file, and run kinit command.

How to config Kerberos in ansible, Kerberos need VM domain join or not?
No active directory accounts to authenticate, only VM username and VM password. what is the process to config VM username and VM Password in Kerberos config file, and login to host machine.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me your KDC is wrong.
You need to go on your windows host. Open a command line and enter the following command :

```
nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.WSUS.COM
```

Expected result :

```
priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = REALKDC
```

Change your KDC in krb5.conf by REALKDC.
And now your kinit command will work normally.

Don't forget to use a username which exist in your AD :

```
kinit myuser
```